# CONREC With An Irregular Grid?

Tags: java, plot, contour

I've been using the CONREC routine to plot some contours for a long time and it's been working fine.  Here's a link to the algorithm:

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/

But now I have an (effectively) irregular grid. I have data with "fill values". So, a grid might look like this:

```
1  6  3  5
3  4  4 -9
4  3  2 -9
2  2 -9 -9
```

Where -9 is designated as the fill value. When I change the fill value to some out of bounds number, like say 100, then it won't create contours for the area, but it will create contours at a steep slope leading to that fill area.  Here's an example:

[image]

Notice the black bands before the magenta color (the gray area is just debugging).  If I use a fill value closer to the range of the data then the banding goes away but it creates contours for the fill area.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to fix this? If not possible using this algorithm are there any other contouring packages that will work with irregular grids? I'm using java so that would be the easiest to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the conrec algorithm doesn't support this. If you want an irregular shape/border you need to use a constrained algorithm. You can use a 2 step algorithm. First off, compute the shape, and second the contour map and then use the shape to determine what pixel is to use from the contour map. You can use a simple color check on the shape and of course check the whole shape. You can try my php implementation of a contour plot at cntm.codeplex.com.